# Check for cookie and log the result in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to check if a cookie exists and if not I want to give the cookie `auth` a `false` value. If the cookie is `false` I want to redirect to `/` and if the cookie is `true` it should redirect to `/home`. Because I can not seem to get it working I removed the redirect and changed it to `console.log("value");` so that I can see if it is working.

```
checkLogin() {
    var AuthCookie = localStorage.getItem("auth");

    if (AuthCookie === null) {
        console.log("null");
        localStorage.setItem("auth", false);
    }

    if (AuthCookie === false) {
        console.log("false");
    }
    else if (AuthCookie === true) {
        console.log("true");
    }
    else {
        console.log("AuthCookie is neither false or true");
    }
}
```

There is no output in the console with this code and I do not know why.

---

I want to store data locally, in this case it is a login page, but this is just to test the storing of the data.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Redirect, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Routes from './inc/routes';
import Navbar from './components/parts/navbar';

class Loader extends Component {
  checkLogin() {
    var AuthCookie = localStorage.getItem("auth");
    if (AuthCookie === null) {
        console.log("null");
        localStorage.setItem("auth", false);
    }

    if (AuthCookie === false) {
        console.log("false");
    }
    else if (AuthCookie === true) {
        console.log("true");
    }
    else {
        console.log("AuthCookie is neither false or true");
    }
}

render() {
    this.checkLogin();
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Routes />
        </div>
    );
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<Loader />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

Console now gives me `AuthCookie is neither false or true`, but when I look at application and localstorage it says that `auth` is `false`. Console shows no other errors or warnings.

Comment: how and when are you calling checkLogin

Comment: localStorage !== cookies. what you are trying to do?

Comment: This code will always log something, providing `checkLogin` is being called, and that there are no errors. So: are there any errors in the console? Are you sure `checkLogin` is being called? (You don't show us any code which calls it.)

Comment: @Dekel sorry, you are right. I first tried it with a cookie, but now am trying with localstorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made 3 mistakes, first was `if (AuthCookie === null)`, this should be `undefined`. The second mistake is that `var AuthCookie` is not updated after `if (AuthCookie === undefined)` so `AuthCookie` is not being updated to the new value. The last mistake is that the value should be in `""` so `(AuthCookie === "false")`.

The correct code working now:

```
var AuthCookie = localStorage.getItem("auth");
if (AuthCookie === undefined) {
   console.log("null");
   localStorage.setItem("auth", false);
}

var AuthCookie = localStorage.getItem("auth");

if (AuthCookie === "false") {
   console.log("false");
}
else if (AuthCookie === "true") {
   console.log("true");
}
else {
   console.log("The cookie is set, but can't be read or has a different value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure AuthCookie is null, perhaps it is undefined, although we can not know without showing where it is assigned to localStorage initially.

Try to work backwards when debugging, so start by console logging AuthCookie when calling the function so you can be sure it is assigned the value you expect. Otherwise go further back to where it is being assigned to localStorage and check the value there. We can not know for sure with the code provided but id say the value is not what you think it is.